# log4j: rolling of logs working but not according to specified size

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using below log4j.xml

```html
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <appender name="file_1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="file"
            value="${catalina.home}/logs/myApp_1.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file_2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
        <param name="file"
            value="${catalina.home}/logs/myApp_2.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <category name="org.springframework">
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="file_1" />
    </category>

    <root>
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="file_1" />
    </root>

    <logger name="test.messageHandler"
        additivity="false">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="file_2" />
    </logger>


</log4j:configuration>
```

according to the configuration file myApp_1.log and myApp_2.log should roll after 10MB.

In my case logs are rolling but after random size

Example:

```
myApp_1.log.1 size 8MB
myApp_1.log.2 size 12MB
etc.
```

same for myApp_2.log file

please suggest what thing I am doing wrong here, log should role just after 10MB

Comment: `log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:..` this warning is just because you did not follow the expected structure of the xml configuration file: 0 or more logger elements followed by 0 or 1 root element. So just alter their place in your file.

Comment: @RDhaval - thanks for your reply,  that warning has gone but logs are still not rolling according to mentioned size